# Запоминание состояния элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Есть скрипт для раскрывающегося списка.
Как можно реализовать запоминание состояния элементов, например, в cookie?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("li:has(ul:has(li))").prepend('<div class="drop"></div>');
    $(".ul-dropfree div.drop").click(function() {
        if ($(this).nextAll("ul").css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideDown(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "-22px 0"
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideUp(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "0 0"
            });
        }
    });
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("ul").slideUp(400).parents("li").children("div.drop").css({
        'background-position': "0 0"
    });
});
```

```css
ul.ul-treefree {
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
ul.ul-treefree ul {
    margin:0;
    padding-left:6px;
}
ul.ul-treefree li {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none outside none;
    border-left:solid 2px #add0de;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 19px;
    line-height:23px;
}
ul.ul-treefree li:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    border-bottom:solid 2px #add0de;
    position:absolute;
    width:18px;
    height:18px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
ul.ul-treefree li:last-child {
    border-left:0 none;
}
ul.ul-treefree li:last-child:before {
    border-left:solid 2px #add0de;
}
ul.ul-dropfree div.drop {
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    top:9px;
    left:-12px;
    background-image: url('../img/plus_minus.png');
    background-position:-11px 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-dropfree ul-treefree">
    <li>
        <p>1</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>1.1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>1.2</li>
            <li>
                <p>1.3</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>1.1.1</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>1.1.2</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>1.4</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>2</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>2.1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>2.2</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>2.2.1</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>2.2.2</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Сохраняйте необходимое параметры элементов в cookie при изменении состояния этих элементов, а при загрузке странице восстанавливайте сохранённые параметры. Для работы с cookie можно использовать, например, [jQuery Cookie](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/). Код, предоставленный в вопросе, и сложен для восприятия, и мало полезен без соответствующего HTML и CSS кода.

Comment: @Regent Поправил вопрос. Просто не очень понятно что записывать в куки...

Comment: Массив значений свойств `display` и `background-position`, например. Ведь, насколько я вижу, меняются в коде только они.